# ScanPower API and retrieving info from a website's sources

Tags: javascript, python, api, http, http-headers

I am working on a freelance application for an online retail company that makes heavy use of ScanPower, a website that aids Amazon shipping and fulfillment. I need to pull records from ScanPower's server, but I cannot find out how to access the information. The URL does not stay the same when I log in to the company's ScanPower account; the login page sends the login information to the server and changes permissions with a POST request. I am stumped on where to go from here. The website, as far as I can tell, is using AJAX to pull records from the server, but I cannot find out how to generate a link to pull information from the server myself. I am using Python urllib3 currently but have been unsuccessful so far.

Has anyone used or familiarized themselves with the ScanPower API or does anyone have a possible solution to the problem?